# Mounting WebDav not working via file manager only via davfs2

Tags: lubuntu, ssl, webdav

I would like to mount my LAN based webdav from a file manager, e.g. PCManFM-Qt.

I am in Lubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, and trying to connect to a WebDav instance augmented to an apache2 web server and self signed ssl certificate.

When using the "connect to remote server" option within PCManFM-Qt with *Secure WebDav*, the host ip on port 443 and the path, and my credentials, I get the status:
[Status when connecting to WebDav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLqUv.png)

When confirming with *Yes*, an error rises: **HTTP Error: Unacceptable TLS certificate**.

When doing it from the command line via davfs2, it works fine, the location gets mounted and appears in the file manager as it is supposed to. Access via a web browser works too, but without sending files or course. Even operation via a WebDav-App on Android works with no problem. So it is on the Lubuntu-20 side I assume.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you are right, guiverc, it is pcmanfm-qt. I just corrected the question. Thank you.